# How control probability of win-lose in tile-matching games?

Tags: algorithm, random

In a random puzzle game, such as a match-three game, how can you control the probability of a winnable starting condition?

Answer (score 2):

You could generate your puzzle by starting with a solved puzzle and then backtrack to an unsolved puzzle by generating a series of random legal player moves which lead to that state.

This is like starting with an already solved rubiks cube, making a couple of random moves, and giving it to a player to solve. You then know that there is at least one solution: repeating the same moves you made in the opposite order. But there could be other solutions, maybe even a better one.

This strategy can be transfered to most other puzzle games which are solved by a series of deterministic moves. The advantage of this method is that you can easily control the difficulty by choosing the number of moves you make.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd also point out the general idea of a Minmax algorithm to him: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax :)

Comment: @Philipp the assumption that the number of moves is bound directly to the difficulty is not true in general case.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to create a solver. The solver can randomly attempt to win. You can calculate the percentage of chance to win. In order to create a winnable stage you need to add new tiles in a way that reverses the move of the player. Meaning that if you add a combination that can be eliminated you simply pick a position to put it and the move the existing tiles in these rows up to accommodate the new pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Computing probability implies that some random process occurs. Here is not clear which random process you are refering to. 
Taking for example a match-tree game, once you have a initial condition there is no more randomness involved: a board may be eighter solveable or not. You may ask "what is the probability of a random board to be solveable", but this is not under your control.

Said that you can control the "difficulty" of board but you have to define what you mean for "difficulty", this kind of metric is strictly bound to the specific game you are modelling and the choice you make for metric is one of the main factors that determine the (in)success of your game.

Comment: "Computing probability implies that some random process occurs." ...if you're a frequentist, that is ;-)

Comment: @Thomas Right, I'm a frequentist here but not here->http://xkcd.com/1132